# how can I add condition on mysql to get value on different table base on column value

Tags: mysql

Good Day,

I have 4 tables that I am trying to join. now I want to get the details of each transaction base on transaction type eg. if

Transaction Table

```
id |     type    |  source_id
 1   'product'         1
 2   'reservation'     1
 3   'service'         1
```

Product Table

```
 id | Name     
  1 | product 1
```

Reservation Table

```
 id | reservation name        | other details
  1 |  some reservation name  | ------
```

Services Table

```
 id | Service Name            | Other details
  1 | House Cleaning Service  | ------------
```

And this is the table I want to get

```
id |     type    |  source_id  | product_name  | reservation_name | service name
 1   'product'         1         product 1           null              null
 2   'reservation'     1             null      some reservation name   null
 3   'service'         1            null             null              House Cleaning Service
```

currently my wildest guess is

```
select a.id,a.type,a.source_id,b.product_name,c.reservation_name,d.service_name
from transaction as a
left join product_table as b on a.source_id = b.id
left join reservation_table as c on a.source_id = c.id
left join services_table as d on a.source_id = d.id
```

and Im sure it wont work 100% :D

is there a way to add a condition that if 'type' column  = 'product' then it only pull from products table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a CASE instruction like this:

```
select a.id,a.type,a.source_id,
       CASE a.source_id
           WHEN 'product'  THEN b.product_name
           else  null
       END ,
       CASE a.source_id
           WHEN 'reservation'  THEN c.reservation_name
           else  null
       END ,
       CASE a.source_id
           WHEN 'service'  THEN d.service_name
           else  null
       END 
from transaction as a
left join product_table as b on a.source_id = b.id
left join reservation_table as c on a.source_id = c.id
left join services_table as d on a.source_id = d.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Add condition in join 
like

```
select a.id,a.type,a.source_id,b.product_name,c.reservation_name,d.service_name
from transaction as a
left join product_table as b on a.source_id = b.id and a.type='product'
left join reservation_table as c on a.source_id = c.id and a.type='reservation'
left join services_table as d on a.source_id = d.id and a.type='service'
```

Comment: wow can u really add condition on join? thanks for the answer!

Comment: yes please mark it right answer if you going to use

Answer (score -1):

```
select  a.id,a.type,a.source_id,b.product_name,c.reservation_name,d.service_name
from transaction as a
left join product_table as b on a.source_id = b.id
left join reservation_table as c on a.source_id = c.id
left join services_table as d on a.source_id = d.id WHERE a.type = 'product'
```

Try this one hope it will help you

Comment: hmm sorry @sushil but im sure this wont work.. by putting where a.type = 'product' that means filtering result to have product types only.. what I need on my question  is to get the three types to be displayed in the same table but on different column based on a.type